# How to add children to QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have the following code, where I'm trying to have two rectangles, and then inside each, display "sub" rectangles (this is the code for one parent and one child)

```
auto graphicsView = std::make_unique<QGraphicsView>();
auto scene = std::make_unique<QGraphicsScene>();
graphicsView->setScene(scene.get());

auto parent1 = std::make_unique<QGraphicsRectItem>(0, 0, 100, 200);
parent1->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::cyan)));

scene->addItem(parent);

auto subRect1 = std::make_unique<QGraphicsRectItem>(10, 10, 50, 50, parent1);
subRect1->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::yellow)));
```

And I was excepting that when I display my `QGraphicsView`, I would see a cyan rectangle (`parent1`), on top of which I would also see a yellow smaller rectangle (`subRect1`), but I'm only able to see the cyan one.

Looking at Qt's documentation, I see that they talk about the fact that `QGraphicsItem` can have children, but why am I not seeing the child here?

PS: I tried adding the child in 3 different ways, but no luck:

1. Passing the parent to the constructor (as I've shown above)
2. Calling `setParentItem` on the child and passing the parent's pointer
3. Calling parent's `childItems()` and then `push_back` or `append` and passing child's pointer to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make_unique won't work here.  When you add an object to the parent in Qt, you've passed off ownership.  The trouble is that you *also* have an unique_ptr which owns it.  As soon as it goes out of scope, it deletes youur object.  Use new instead.

```
auto graphicsView = new QGraphicsView();
auto scene = new QGraphicsScene();
graphicsView->setScene(scene);

auto parent1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 200);
parent1->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::cyan)));

scene->addItem(parent);

auto subRect1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(10, 10, 50, 50, parent1);
subRect1->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::yellow)));
```

(This is not fully exception proof, but Qt isn't designed to use exceptions.  You could make scene, for example, with make_unique and then hand it off to the graphicsView with release(), but in practice nobody ever does that with Qt.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I marked it as my answer. Just wanted to add: another way to make sure nothing is deleted is to make everything a class member field, so that, as you mentioned, nothing goes out of scope and gets deleted

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  In c++, whenever you make an object, you need to know who owns it, who will delete it, and who you might hand ownership to.

Comment: Just a quick question: when we specify the values for the child rectangle, is it relative to its parent item or relative to the scene itself?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that versed in that area.